# Young slits, mirrors and interference patterns

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reflection, double-slit-experiment

Why do Young slits projecting via an intermediary mirror to a screen still shows the normal pattern of interference?
This happens even though the mirror is so close that not all interference is constructed yet. The more dramatic experiment being to use a mirror for each slit so as to split and then using two other mirrors to recombine the light.
It is my understanding from QM that the interference pattern only happens because there is no measurement between the slits and the screen. However, I don't see how the mirror avoids any measurement at all.
Do mirrors somehow escape measuring light and if so, what is the justification for this exception? I find it even harder to accept this possibility considering the mechanical effect of radiation pressure on the mirror.

Comment: Maybe it'll be better if you add a diagram for better understanding?

Comment: Maybe, but I cannot due to technical limitations here.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119743/qm-why-is-reflection-of-a-photon-not-a-measurement/119749#119749

Comment: I would like to clear up that Youngs experiment with light does not need quantum mechanics, classical electromagnetic wave equations work fine.. It is only for massive particles and single photon double slit that quantum mechanics needs to be invoked . https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Comment: @anna v: the measurement problem is a QM one.

Comment: @alanf: thanks. Reading your post, it seems to me this is the same as saying measurement can be graded and have almost zero impact on light coherence in the context of reflection, right? I had imagine measurement as a binary process, either having place or not at all. I noticed you talking about probabilities though, thus it can still be a binary process yet happening with a graded probability.

Comment: You should state then that it is the specific measurement problem.  Classical scattering has no problem with mirrors. In QM  mirrors work with elastic scattering of the photons and the phases are retained., coherence is not lost, and as the mass of the  mirror is very large with respect to the energy of the photon the effect of momentum transfer changes the frequency by a very small amount, not visible in colors.

Comment: You should give a specific diagram to see where you see a measurement problem.

Comment: @anna v: I did mention the measurement problem and the inability to provide a diagram.

Comment: well, if there is no diagram how can one answer? At the quantum mechanical level it is all about boundary conditions for the solution of the quantum mechanical set up.  Do you have a link? where somebody has seen these interferences  using mirrors?

Comment: Any interferometer based on semireflective mirrors will do.

Comment: There is a series of MIT videos which show the difference between interference and interaction among other things. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU .photons interfere by superposition of their wavefunctions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93447/discussion-between-exocytosis-and-anna-v).