# How particles are seperated to prove the existence of quantum entanglement?

Tags: soft-question

I understand that quantum entanglement has been proven but I could not find on the internet how they have separated the required particles far away. Can anyone describe it a bit or send me a link to understand how the experiment was performed? Specifically, how the experiment was performed based on which Nobel prize was awarded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QM: why is reflection of a photon not a measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119743/qm-why-is-reflection-of-a-photon-not-a-measurement)

Comment: @hft Sorry, I did not get the relation to my question and your link. People got the Nobel prize for the proof and I am asking bit of details about the experiment.

Comment: You didn't write that you were specifically asking about the Nobel prize winning experiment. That would be helpful to add to your question if that is what you are interested in.

Comment: Did you check to Nobel website to see if they published the recipients' Nobel lectures or other explanatory material?

Comment: @hft, Thank you for your comment. I edited the question. Sorry, I assumed that a  particular experiment was the cause and it would be obvious.

Comment: https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2022/10/fig4_fy_en_22_BellExperiments.pdf

Comment: https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2022/10/advanced-physicsprize2022.pdf

Comment: @hft Honestly, I did not. The reality is I did not even know that such a website exists. Recently I got the news and got excited to find the experiment details, could not find them by searching the net, so I asked. Now I will look for the website. Thanks.

Comment: I posted links to some relevant PDFs on the website (above)

Comment: @hft Thank you so much. Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for.